# "Barplot like" histogram with a probability density curves in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have 2 groups of data, which I represented using barplot. To the same data I fitted a mixture model and I would like to plot the probability densities I've got over my data in barplot. The problem I encountered is that the values on the x axis in barplot (step is 1.1) are different from the intervals I used for calculating probability density ( step is 0.01), so the probability densities are squeezed. If I change the step size when fitting probability densities to the data, the lines are kinked, which does not look nice.

I tried to use a histogram, which works well for plotting probability densities, however I only managed to plot 2 histograms on the same graph, but I want my data to be represented in the way that barplot does.

Could someone please advise me how I can do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include your attempted solution(s)

Comment: Some sample data would help a lot too.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to plot a kernel density on top of a barplot

Answer (score 0):

usually I use ggplot package. But I never tried to do this. However, try this code:

{ ##Create your model e.g.

```
model <- lm(Y ~ X , your_data)

## Create a data frame with X column, interpolating across range
xmin <- min(your_data$X)
xmax <- max(your_data$X)
predict <- data.frame(X=seq(xmin, xmax, length.out=100))
## Calculate predicted values of Y
predict$Y <- predict(model, predict)
## Create a boxplot graph
  library(ggplot2)
  graph<-ggplot(your_data, aes(x=, y =)) + 
         geom_boxplot()
## Add your predicted value.
graph + geom_smooth(data=predict, method="loess", color="red", aes(group=1))
```

}

I can not add a graph because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: n future, use the `{}` button to enclose your code in a code block.

Comment: You should probably get rid of the `library(ggplot2)` since you're not using it here. And, since `boxplot` is from base graphics, you can't add `lines` with `+`.... and the OP is asking about `barplot`, not `boxplot`.